# The middle cell in CSS table is not centered properly

Tags: html, css-tables

Why the middle cell is not centered when the screen is wide?

I've tried to center almost everithing in ther but still cannot see the results I need.

[image: e]

Here is a link: http://edm-norway.com/4d

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a grid-based CSS framework, like Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="container-fluid grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 column">
      <a href="http://edm-norway.com/4d/logos">our services</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 column">
      <a href="http://mechanisms.club">our project</a></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 column">
      <a href="http://ecofarm.technology">our startup</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">a picture is worth a thousand words
</div>
```

See the result I got **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/k4vpfyjq/4/)**. As you can see, on extra small screen resolutions, the blocks **stack**. You won't be able to stack table cells or headers.

UPDATE:

Your Header section should be:

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    body {
      background: #333333ff;
      font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
      font-size: 25px;
    }

    img {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 240px;
      height: auto;
    }

    .footer {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      color: #f2f2f2ff;
      font-size: 20px;
      background-color: #4a4a4aff;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    a,
    a:hover {
      color: #f2f2f2ff;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .grid .column {
      font-weight: normal;
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    @media (min-width: 576px) {
      .grid .column {
        height: 100px;
      }
    }

  </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can give anyone  with:33.33

Answer (score 0):

table cell change width with text size. You have to set equal width to table cells

```
th {
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate. you can mark the answer as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The table and its cells are all centered. It seems you are trying to align the middle cell with the logo above, I would suggest you move the logo to the left manually, using margin:-10px, if this is what you want.

As a test trying shrinking your browser window, you would see the middle cell align at some point and loose alignment.